# regex help splitting string on the hyphen and space characters in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a string as follows:

```
"IPF-Plasma 1"
```

I'd like to split on "-" and "\\s". I tried the following:

```
strsplit(cleanData[[1]][1,1], "-|s")
```

However, it gives,

```
    > strsplit(cleanData[[1]][1,1], "-|s")
[[1]]
[1] "IPF"  "Pla"  "ma 1"
```

Why is there a split on "Plasma"? And how would I fix it?

Comment: You could use `strsplit(yourstring, '[- ]')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You had it... you forgot the slashes...

```
a <- "IPF-Plasma 1"
> strsplit(a, "-|s")
[[1]]
[1] "IPF"  "Pla"  "ma 1"

> strsplit(a, "-|\\s")
[[1]]
[1] "IPF"    "Plasma" "1"
```

Comment: argh -- it's always the simple things. I stared at it for 5 minutes and didn't realize that "Plasma" has an "s". Sigh. Thanks!